# find match occurrences and copy to sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, find, excel-2010

I have some VBA experience, I can read and understand the coding, but have problems finding the proper codes.

Now, I have a userform where by the user would key in his ID, excel would then open up the database and search and return the results of the cells beside the found ID. the results would be returned and overwrite label 1 and label 2. And when the user clicks on the "next" or "previous" button, the next or previous results would then overwrite both labels.

The code I have right now allows me to search for the locations of the found ID and output the location in a format such as ($A$2,$A$3,$A$4,$A$6). The problem is that I am not sure what is the right functions that can then break this into individual range that the "next" or "previous" button can then refer to.

Have added my code

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim bcell As Range
Dim foundat As String
Dim oRange As Range
Dim userid As String
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim Prob As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("OFI")
Set oRange = ws.Columns(1)
userid = txt_user.Text


Set cell = oRange.Find(what:=userid, after:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If Not cell Is Nothing Then
    Set bcell = cell
    foundat = cell.Address
    Do
        Set cell = oRange.FindNext(after:=cell)

        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            If cell.Address = bcell.Address Then Exit Do
            foundat = foundat & ", " & cell.Address
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
Else
    msgbox userid & "not found"
    Exit Sub
End If

capproblem_output.Caption = foundat


Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two command buttons with name `cmdNext` & `cmdPrev` , label with name `capproblem_output2`  to run the below code. Copy the code to userform code section.

```
Public foundat As String

Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
    capproblem_output.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)
    capproblem_output2.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPrev_Click()
    capproblem_output.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1)
    capproblem_output2.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1)
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Main
End Sub


Sub Main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim bcell As Range

    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim userid As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim Prob As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("OFI")
    Set oRange = ws.Columns(1)
    userid = UserForm1.txt_user.Text


    Set cell = oRange.Find(what:=userid, after:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        Set bcell = cell
        foundat = cell.Address
        Do
            Set cell = oRange.FindNext(after:=cell)

            If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                If cell.Address = bcell.Address Then Exit Do
                foundat = foundat & ", " & cell.Address
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    Else
        MsgBox userid & "not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    capproblem_output.Caption = Range(foundat).Offset(0, 1)
    capproblem_output2.Caption = Range(foundat).Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Oops, totally forgot to answer this. Had problems understanding it at first, and spent a while messing with it. Then i forgot about this. Thanks for the help man!